# What is the architecture of my Node .js / React, Redux application using microservices

Tags: node.js, reactjs, design-patterns, architecture, mern

I am using in my application:

Backend : Nodejs, Express, Passport js and Mongoose, the project structure is : models with mongoose , controllers and routes. What do we call this architecture ?

Frontend : React , Redux  and reactstrap : What do we call this architecture ?

And deployment in microservices using k8s and api gateway.

I need to know what types of architecture(software, application and system)  this is ? and what type of design pattern ?

what's the difference between MVC Architecture, microservices Architectur and multilayer Architecture ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a server-side programming language (Node and Express in your case) and database (MongoDB in your case), then it is just **backend architecture** (as they are just used to create the backend of a web application).

Now, if you decided to use React Js in the frontend along with backend (Node, Express, and MongoDB) then, it is known as **MVC architecture** as View (ReactJs is added here). The combination of programming stacks such as MongoDB, Express, ReactJS, and NodeJs is known as the **MERN stack** design pattern.

Similarly, **Microservices Architecture** is one where multiple platforms (programming language) are used to build an application. For example, you can use NodeJs (Express) to build an authentication module, Python (Django) to develop a file uploads module, and so on.

Lastly, **Multilayer Architecture** is one where an application is separated in multiple layers, 3-layers usually viz. presentation, application and data layer. The presentation layer (or client) is responsible for displaying information to the user (Ex. web browser in a web application) whereas the application layer (or server) consists of business logic and is responsible for serving client's requests (Ex. web server in a web application). Lastly, the database server acts as a data layer, and the application layer interact with it to process requests.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am using a Microservices Architecture and each module is developped using MongoDB, Express, ReactJS and NodeJs so my software application is called MVC architecture ? and in Cliend SIde is my software application is called Redux architecture ? 

Thank you

Comment: No @DevGeek344, It is still MVC architecture. Redux is just a state management library for JavaScript applications in frontend. You can use MongoDB to develop Model, Node + Express to develop Controller and React+Redux to developer View in MVC architecture. Here, Model and Controller are considered as backend (or server) and View is considered as frontend (or client).